# How do I prevent a "The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process" error while trying to move a file?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, apache-poi

This is a tester code to try  to implement a feature. This feature is moving a file to a new directory if it is bigger than a certain size as to not generate files that are too big.
However I am encountering this error every time while using the .move() method on the file:

Exception in thread "main" java.nio.file.FileSystemException: C:\Users\Public\Operational_Functional_Block\src\obf_reg.docx -> C:\Users\Public\Operational_Functional_Block\src\FullFolders\obf.reg[Full].docx:

The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process

java.base/sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.translateToIOException(WindowsException.java:92)
java.base/sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.rethrowAsIOException(WindowsException.java:103)
java.base/sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileCopy.move(WindowsFileCopy.java:403)
java.base/sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileSystemProvider.move(WindowsFileSystemProvider.java:293)
java.base/java.nio.file.Files.move(Files.java:1432)
com.example.demo.Tester.main(Tester.java:44)

here is the tester file (I'm using apache POI and IntelliJ):

```
package com.example.demo;

import java.io.*;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;

import org.apache.poi.openxml4j.util.ZipSecureFile;
import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.*;

import static java.nio.file.StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING;

public class Tester {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        ZipSecureFile.setMinInflateRatio(0.001);
        File pathn1 = new File("C:\\Users\\Public\\Operational_Functional_Block\\src\\obf_reg.docx");
        if (!(new File(String.valueOf(pathn1)).exists())) {
            XWPFDocument docx12 = new XWPFDocument();
            XWPFParagraph par1 = docx12.createParagraph();
            XWPFRun run1 = par1.createRun();
            run1.setText("...---...");
            run1.addBreak();
            try (FileOutputStream out1 = new FileOutputStream(String.valueOf(pathn1))) {
                docx12.write(out1);
                out1.close();
                docx12.close();
            }
        }
        String repeatCommand = "whatever";
        while (!repeatCommand.equals("N")) {
            Path path = Paths.get(String.valueOf(pathn1));
            if (Files.size(path) < 2350) {
                System.out.println("size" + "------>" + Files.size(path));
            } else {
                File logM = new File("C:\\Users\\Public\\Operational_Functional_Block\\src\\FullFolders");
                logM.mkdir();
                // ------------------------------
                File pathn2 = new File("C:\\Users\\Public\\Operational_Functional_Block\\src\\obf_reg.docx");
                //File pathn3 = new File("C:\\Users\\Public\\Operational_Functional_Block\\src\\obf_reg[Full].docx");
                //pathn2.renameTo(pathn3);
                // ------------------------------
                Path normPF = Paths.get(String.valueOf(pathn2));
                Path logPF = Paths.get("C:\\Users\\Public\\Operational_Functional_Block\\src\\FullFolders\\obf.reg[Full].docx");
                Files.move(normPF, logPF, REPLACE_EXISTING);
                // ------------------------------
                File file1 = new File("C:\\Users\\Public\\Operational_Functional_Block\\src\\obf_reg.docx");
                file1.createNewFile();
                // ------------------------------
                XWPFDocument docx1 = new XWPFDocument();
                XWPFParagraph par21 = docx1.createParagraph();
                XWPFRun run21 = par21.createRun();
                run21.setText("...---...");
                run21.addBreak();
                try (FileOutputStream out1 = new FileOutputStream(String.valueOf(pathn1))) {
                    docx1.write(out1);
                    out1.close();
                    docx1.close();
                }
            }
            XWPFDocument docx = new XWPFDocument();
            if (new File(String.valueOf(pathn1)).exists()) {
                docx = new XWPFDocument(new FileInputStream(String.valueOf(pathn1)));
            }
            XWPFParagraph par2 = docx.createParagraph();
            XWPFRun run2 = par2.createRun();
            run2.setText("...---...");
            run2.addBreak();
            try (FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(String.valueOf(pathn1))) {
                docx.write(out);
            }
            System.out.println("did thing...");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: There might be a lock on the file. If so, try copying it then deleting the original. You can queue for deletion. You can make life easier for yourself by using forward slashes in place of doubled back slashes

Comment: what do you mean by queue for deletion?

Comment: Well I meant you can collect all files for deletion into a queue and then run that at once when other processing is finished

Comment: i tried to do what your first comment said and it gave me the same error

Comment: Seems the file `C:\\Users\\Public\\Operational_Functional_Block\\src\\FullFolders\\obf.reg[Full].docx` is locked. But that is not caused by something in your code. Is that file opened in Excel? Then the operating system locked that file.

Comment: can file explorer lock it? because that's the only one. BTW I'm using IntelliJ just in case it's the IDE causing this

Comment: I managed to fix "the file being used by another process" but now I'm getting "NoSuchFileException"

Comment: nvm its fixed now

Answer (score 0):

i should have used .copy instead of .move lol

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).